# How to set button in side stackpanel to right edge in windows 10 universal app development

Tags: c#, xaml, stackpanel

I an new to windows app development,i searched for this but not found any where.I need the button at right edge and Stretch the textbox till buttons start.But I am unable to set the button to Right edge.

How to acheve this.

Answer (score 0):

A stackpanel works like a container. If you define layout properties on your stackpanel, then the objects inside your stackpanel cannot be displayed outside of the stackpanel's limits.

For example :
If I set my row and column number in my stackpanel,

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Name="Version" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Label Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="6" Name="Ver" Content="V." HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
    <TextBlock Name="Vers" Text="1.0" TextAlignment="Right" />
</StackPanel>
```

Then the row/column properties set on my label are ignored and the 'HorizontalAlignment="Right"' will place my label on the right side of the stackpanel, not the grid.

A solution may be to remove your button from your stackpanel, you are then free to place your button anywhere on the grid.

Another solution can be to expand your stackpanel's limits.
To do so, you can use the Grid.ColumnSpan property or simply set your stackpanel on the right of the grid.

Hope that helped.